# How do open a PDF in the background in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a very simple script that is used to rename PDF files. The procedure is quite simple; I have to open the PDF to see what I should name that particular file. Sometimes I have up towards 100 PDFs to rename.

The script looks like this:

```
import os

path =  os.getcwd()
filenames = os.listdir(path)
prefix = input("Vad ska stå innan? ")

for filename in filenames:
    if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
        filepath = path + "\\" + filename
        print(filename)
        os.startfile(filepath)
        nyttNamn = input("Nytt namn: ")
        nyttNamn = prefix + " " + nyttNamn + ".pdf"
        os.rename(filename, nyttNamn)
    else:
        continue
```

My only problem is that when I open the PDF (which opens in chrome, in a new tab), I have to alt+tab back to the shell to let the loop continue to the next PDF file.

Is there someway I can either open the PDF in the background, so that I am still in the shell and can write, or somehow automatically open it and go back to the shell window?

Comment: Why do you do `f = open(filename)`? Do you read from the `f` variable somewhere?

Comment: Yeah good question - it was from my first attempt at doing this, just didn't delete it.

Comment: So edit the question to not confuse anyone.

Comment: you visually inspect the pdf and input() the new name?

Comment: Yeah, that is what the script is doing. Its opening the PDF, and I input the new name. The problem is when the file opens, I have to alt-tab back, which i kind of want to automate.

Comment: AFAIK little can be done here without digging in WinAPI modules. You can prevent a new application to become active (grab keyboard and mouse) from the `subprocess` module, you could even choose where to display it on the screen but you cannot prevent the last created window to become the topmost window. And I could not find anything from Python (except calling WinAPI function via `ctypes`) to bring back the Python window on top.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use something like:

```
import os
path = "/var/www/pdfs/"
dirs = os.listdir(path)

for file in dirs:
   os.rename(file, newfilename)
```

More information about os.rename [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_rename.htm).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand how that would change back to the shell window after the PDF has been opened?

Comment: do you actually need to open pdf and see the content in browser to rename the file or just want to enter the new filename for each file in the terminal ?

Comment: Both - first I have to open the PDF in the browser, which is besides the terminal, and after that I'll write into the terminal what I want the new name to be.